# Github Desktop failed to clone a repo from Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, github-desktop

When I use Github Desktop (Ver 2.5.0) to clone a repo from Gitlab, I always got 'Authentication failed',like this:
[image]

I've seen the tutorial how to clone a repo from gitlab, in this step, I should got a window to input my username and pwd , but not.
How can I solve it ?
THX!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem , cause the github desktop latest release version 2.5.0 has a issue #9843 . That is a  bug to make ur app cannot access ur gitlab account. And it was fixed in next release of this production of the app.